# Intent - addBackStack(null) for Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity, back-stack

We can use addBackStack(null) with Fragments and in this way the fragment won't open when we press back. But how we can do this with Activity? I could'n find an usage about that.
I also tried this:

```
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
```

but this is not working.

And finally `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)` is working but when I take application to background and reopen it this activity is destroyed.

Comment: I assume you're talking about `addToBackStack()` from `FragmentTransaction`. This method adds the current `FragmentTransaction` to the back stack rather than removing it. When you then exit another `Fragment` on top of it you'll return to the one in the back stack. Is this what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I remember when we set `addToBackStack` to `null` the current fragment must be removed. But maybe I remember wrong. I solved this problem. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure of what your problem was to begin with, that's why I asked for clarification. Activities are automatically added to the back stack and no extra flags are necessary for that to work.
It seems to me like you wanted to achieve the _opposite_ of what you were asking for which is to _remove_ something from the back stack instead of adding it like your question implies. By finishing your old `Activity` you're achieving exactly that so your solution seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I understand there is no need for Flags. The problem was solved with adding finish() when open other activity.

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
finish();  
startActivity(i);
```